# How to center the US location in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to center the location's center in us map in map Kit view

I am sending my code here

```
mapView .scrollEnabled = YES;
    appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    dataStore = [[DataStore alloc] init];
    utility = [[Utility alloc] init];

    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 28, mapView.frame.size.width, mapView.frame.size.height)];
    //[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self setMapView:mapView];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

region.center.latitude = 41.603854;
    region.center.longitude = -92.930628;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 47.00;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 10.00;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the region once you set it up.

```
region.center.latitude = 41.603854;
region.center.longitude = -92.930628;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 47.00;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 10.00;

[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```